# Mixed Content Problem with TYPO3, Kubernetes and a docker apache image

Tags: apache, docker, kubernetes, typo3, typo3-9.x

We have a running TYPO3 9.5.7 System on a kubernetes Cluster. TYPO3 runs on a docker container with PHP7.3-apache. The complete site has an SSL (Let's Encrypt) certificate. I can load the TYPO3 Backend. Now, if I try to activate an extension with the extensionmanager I got the following error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my.domain.com/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=b264e888080675e401a2a6162a9e7be22f968b7e' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://my.domain.com/typo3/index.php?route=%2Ftools%2FExtensionmanagerExtensionmanager%2F&token=8ab8e4a2eef2832bf7ff4615b9787642cadc6e01&tx_extensionmanager_tools_extensionmanagerextensionmanager%5BextensionKey%5D=of_customisation&tx_extensionmanager_tools_extensionmanagerextensionmanager%5Baction%5D=unresolvedDependencies&tx_extensionmanager_tools_extensionmanagerextensionmanager%5Bcontroller%5D=List'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Has anyone an idea what I have to do to get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should let TYPO3 know that it [runs behind a HTTPS reverse proxy](https://moc.net/om-moc/aktuelt/blogs/tech/running-typo3-cms-behind-https-proxy) in your `LocalConfiguration.php`:

```php
'SYS' => [
    'reverseProxyIP' => 'THE IP OF YOUR PROXY SERVER',
    'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'last',
    'reverseProxySSL' => '*',
],
```

See the list of options on this topic [in the TYPO3 source](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/71cb708d764eba2614608558e85f4a7dc31fee47/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfigurationDescription.yaml#L151-L169):

- `reverseProxyIP`: List of IP addresses. If TYPO3 is behind one or more (intransparent) reverse proxies the IP addresses must be added here.
- `reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue`: Defines which values of a proxy header (eg HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR) to use, if more than one is found.
- `reverseProxyPrefix`: Optional prefix to be added to the internal URL (SCRIPT_NAME and REQUEST_URI).
- `reverseProxySSL`: `'*'` or list of IP addresses of proxies that use SSL (https) for the connection to the client, but an unencrypted connection (http) to the server. If `'*'` all proxies defined in `[SYS][reverseProxyIP]` use SSL.
- `reverseProxyPrefixSSL`: Prefix to be added to the internal URL (SCRIPT_NAME and REQUEST_URI) when accessing the server via an SSL proxy. This setting overrides `[SYS][reverseProxyPrefix]`.

Comment: That seems not to help. Which IP should I use? I tried the IP from the nodes and from the ingress loadbalancer from where the website is reachable. But I always get the same error.

Comment: You need to set the IP address of the load balancer in `reverseProxyIP` on each node.

Comment: ok, that seems to help. Now I've the problem that the $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] listen to 80 but the TYPO3_SSL set the defaultport to 443. To solve this problem, you have to set the trustedHostsPattern in LocalConfiguration to the domain. Currently is that the only way to do that?